# Programmatically determine assembly dependencies

Tags: .net

like the subject says, I want to programmatically enumerate the assemblies to which an assembly of which I have the DLL refers in order to resolve the dependencies.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getreferencedassemblies.aspx) does what you want. Simple call this recursively for each assembly

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the [`Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getreferencedassemblies.aspx).